# How to find all files executable by specific user (not current)

Tags: linux, find

How to find all files which can be executed by specific user (not current!)

For current I can do it like

```
find /some/start/dir -executable
```

But now I want to do something like: find all files which user 'josh' can execute (by 'other' permissions, 'user' permissions and 'group' permissions). Of course, I do not know users's 'josh' password so I cannot su'ing.

Answer (score 3):

Look up the user id of "josh" in /etc/passwd.

Then run: **find /some/start/dir -type "f" -uid <ID> -perm 111**.

Comment: Nope, it just find files owned by this UID but not executable by this user!

Comment: You're right. -executable can only check permissions for the current user as the `access()` syscall is used.

I edited the answer, this solution is working. Though, keep in mind that ACL or other access models may still deny executability (-execute doesn't inherit this problem for the current user).

Assuming you don't use ACL or extended security mechanisms, this method will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread, but I had to do this recently and it is still relevant.

Since we're talking about *nix permissions, one tedious yet thorough way to approach this is by looking at the membership that the ID has on the system:

ie:

```
# assuming josh is a member of group "grpname"

find / -user josh -perm -100     # gets files owned by josh & are executable
find / -group grpname -perm -010 # gets files with grp ownership and executable
                                 #        via group 
                                 #     Must be repeated for each group josh is in
find / -perm -001                # gets files executable by any user
```

Note there could be some overlap for files that josh owns but are also owned by group "grpname". A sort|uniq would filter those out pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks Tim, this really saved me a lot of time. Hard to find such complete answer. Thanks!